# python IPC (Inter Process Communication) for Vista UAC (User Access Control)

Tags: python, windows-vista, wxpython, ipc, vista-security

I am writing a Filemanager in (wx)python - a lot already works. When copying files there is already a progress dialog, overwrite handling etc.

Now in Vista when the user wants to copy a file to certain directories (eg %Program Files%) the application/script needs elevation, which cannot be asked for at runtime. So i have to start another app/script elevated, which does the work, but needs to communicate with the main app, so latter can update the progress etc.

I searched and found a lot of articles saying shared memory and pipes are the easiest way. So what i am looking for is a 'high level' platform independent ipc library whith python bindings using shared mem or pipes.

I already found ominORB, fnorb, etc. They look very interesting, but use TCP/IP, is there an equivalent lib using shared mem or pipes ? Since the ipc-client is always on the same machine sockets seems not to be neccesary here. And i am also afraid the user would have to allow ipc-socket-communications on his/her personal firewall.

EDIT: I really mean high level: it would be great to be able to just call some functions like when using omniORB instead of sending strings to stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 2):

How about just communicating with the second process using stdin/stdout?

There are some caveats due to input and output buffering, but take a look at [this Python Cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440554/), and also [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect), for ideas on how to do this.

Comment: thanks, i edited my question to stress, that i want to be able to call a function like with omniORB.